# jquery.filer Plugin stop instant image upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, image-uploading

im useing this plugin [jquery.filer](https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.filer#support)

It works so far good exept that my images get uploaded at the time i select them, does anybody know how to disable this?

I want the images be uploaded when the submit button is clicked..

In Doc i found this:
addMore Multiple file selection without instant uploading {Boolean}

I have set "addMore" to true and false, but the images get allways instantly uploadet..

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set `uploadFile` option to `null`.